# Why is my schema.org rating markup for a place not being shown by Google?

Tags: schema.org, google-search-console, microdata

I am trying to introduce Schema.org microdata for showing rating-stars in Google search results. For this, I use the Google Structured Data Testing Tool (Google Webmaster Tools), to test my code. The following snippet doesn't work:

```
<article itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Place">
    <div class="rating" itemprop="aggregateRating" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/AggregateRating">
        <meta itemprop="ratingValue" content="4" />
        <meta itemprop="bestRating" content="5" />
        <meta itemprop="ratingCount" content="1" />
    </div>
    <div class="content"><h1 itemprop="name">This is my Page name</h1></div>
</article>
```

Has anyone an idea, why not or what to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google will not typically display an aggregate rating rich snippet for a "Place" itemtype. They do show it, though, for more specific place types, such as for restaurants and other local business types.  So you might need to get more specific with your markup.

On a different note, hiding marked up content such as with meta tags goes against Google's guidelines. So you might want to address that, too.

I hope this helps.

David

Comment: Thank you very much. I found that out too, but the only specific type I could use is LandmarksOrHistoricalBuildings or TouristAttraction, which are both not shown by google :(. And I just use Meta-Tags, since I display the rating stars as (repeating) background images.